# import org.ros.rosjava.android.MessageCallable error

Tags: rosjava, eclipse, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all:

I downloaded source from https://code.google.com/p/rosjava.android/. And I **rosmake android_tutorial_pubsub**. Then I imported this project into Eclipse. However, I got errors, which are

**import org.ros.rosjava.android.MessageCallable;
import org.ros.rosjava.android.views.RosTextVie**w;

It seems that the project did not import **org.ros.rosjava.android.***
Does anyone could help me? Thanks!!!!!!!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11262/import-org.ros.rosjava.android.messagecallable-error/) by [leon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1100/leon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like there is a Android library dependency. Check that the project properties has a green check mark next to the android_gingerbread library. You probably have not imported the necessary Android library projects into Eclipse.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0